# AVQueuePlayer doesn’t play wav file smoothly from remote URL. It is choppy and stops in the middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

Here is code for initialise AVQueuePlayer.

```
AVQueuePlayer *queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
    queuePlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

    if ([queuePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling)])
            queuePlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = NO;

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    if (playerItem)
            [queuePlayer insertItem:playerItem afterItem:nil];

    if ([queuePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(playImmediatelyAtRate:)])
                [queuePlayer playImmediatelyAtRate:1.0];
    else [queuePlayer play];
```

Comment: is the audio file plays well on other players?

Comment: Yes, it plays fine in browser and android too.

Comment: it stop in the middle and  'addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:CMTimeMake(100, 1000) ' keeps execute.